# Is it possible to run tasks on Windows Compute Engines with Google Batch?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

From the documentation I get the impression that Google Batch jobs can run on Compute Engines.
But when I tried to set up Google Batch, I didn't get the option to select a windows image.
Is this not possible? Would it be better to use Azure Batch instead?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Batch does not support Windows OS. Batch seems to only support Linux based images such as Debian, CentOS, and container optimized OS.